# python not iterating by line with readlines()

Tags: python

I have a text file with just strings on each row. I want to get python to look at a row and then check if that string is in a list and if it is not add it, else skip to next line. Later I will use collections to count total occurrences of each list item.

```
testset = ['2']
# '2' is just a "sanity check" value that lets me know I am extending list

file = open('icecream.txt')

filelines = file.readlines()

for i in filelines:
    if i not in testset:
    testset.extend(i)
else:
    print(i, "is already in set")

print(testset)
```

I was expecting to get:

```
testset = ['2', 'chocolate', 'vanilla', 'AmericaConeDream', 'cherrygarcia', ...]
```

instead I got:

```
testset = ['2', 'c', 'h', 'o', 'c', 'o' ....]
```

Not sure what is happening here. I have tried to run this using:
    for i in file:

As I believe I read on another post that the open() was a iterator in and of itself. Can someone enlighten me as to how I get this iteration to work?

Comment: I think the issue is that you're using `extend`, which expects an iterable. Use `testset.append(i)` and see how it goes.

Comment: Does the order matter here? You could just do `testset = set(file)`

Comment: `'chocolate', 'vanilla', ... etc. ` are on same line ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`extend()` iterates over the elements (in this case, the characters) of its argument, and adds each of the them individually to the list. Use `append()` instead:

```
    testset.append(i)
```

If you don't care about the order in which the lines appear in `testset`, you could use a set instead of a list. The following one-liner will create a set containing every unique line in the file:

```
testset = set(open('icecream.txt'))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can think of `extend` as `append` for an an iterable of values rather than just one. Because you plan to use a counter to counter the files anyway, I would do the following to key the unique values:

```
with open('text.txt') as text:
    data = Counter(i for i in text) # try data.keys()
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: look at [NPE's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29953569/450517): it's basically the same, but more elegant and pythonic.

Try reading and splitting and reducing in one go:

```
textset = set(file.read().split('\n'))
```